# Find H Index of the nodes of a graph using NetworkX

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, graph, networkx, graph-algorithm

**Definition of H Index used in this algorithm**

Supposing a relational expression is represented as y = F(x1, x2, . . . , xn), where F returns an integer number greater than 0, and the function is to find a maximum value y satisfying the condition that there exist at least y elements whose values are not less than y. Hence, the H-index of any node i is defined as

H(i) = F(kj1 ,kj2 ,...,k jki)

where kj1, kj2, . . . , kjki represent the set of degrees of neighboring nodes of node i.

Now I want to find the H Index of the nodes of the following graphs using the algorithm given below :

**Graph** :
[image]

**Code** (Written in Python and NetworkX) :

```
def hindex(g, n):
  nd = {}
  h = 0
  # print(len(list(g.neighbors(n))))
  for v in g.neighbors(n):
    #nd[v] = len(list(g.neighbors(v)))
    nd[v] = g.degree(v)
    snd = sorted(nd.values(), reverse=True)
    for i in range(0,len(snd)):
      h = i
      if snd[i] < i:
        break
  #print("H index of " + str(n)+ " : " + str(h))
  return h
```

**Problem** :
This algorithm is returning the wrong values of nodes 1, 5, 8 and 9

**Actual Values** :

Node 1 - 6 : H Index = 2

Node 7 - 9 : H Index = 1

But for Node 1 and 5 I am getting 1, and for Node 8 and 9 I am getting 0.

Any leads on where I am going wrong will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean Node 7 - 9 : H Index = 1?

Comment: Oh yes sorry I made a mistake

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
def hindex(g, n):
    sorted_neighbor_degrees = sorted((g.degree(v) for v in g.neighbors(n)), reverse=True)
    h = 0
    for i in range(1, len(sorted_neighbor_degrees)+1):
        if sorted_neighbor_degrees[i-1] < i:
            break
        h = i

    return h
```

There's no need for a nested loop; just make a decreasing list, and calculate the h-index like normal.

The reason for 'i - 1' is just that our arrays are 0-indexed, while h-index is based on rankings (i.e. the k largest values) which are 1-indexed.

From the definition of h-index: For a non-increasing function f, h(f) is max i >= 0 such that f(i) >= i. This is, equivalently, the min i >= 1 such that f(i) < i, minus 1. Here, f(i) is equal to sorted_neighbor_degrees[i - 1]. There are of course many other ways (with different time and space requirements) to calculate h.

Comment: @wamika The reason for i-1 is just that our arrays are 0-indexed, while h-index is based on ranks (i.e. the k largest values) which are 1-indexed. To explain the rest a bit: 
Since the h-index h is the largest i such that f(i) >= i. we can instead break when we find the smallest i such that f(i) < i; then, h is i - 1.

Comment: @kcsquared Comments tend to disappear unexpectedly; you should add that explanation about 0-index and 1-index in the answer.